# Constraint - Derived Class must have a default Constructor

Tags: php, c++

I want to Constraint that the Derived Class must have a Default Constructor.
I am currently thinking it in a perverted way

```
template <typename Derived>
class Base{
  public:
    Base(){

    }
    virtual ~Base(){
      new Derived;
    }
};
```

Another idea comes to mind is to keep a pure virtual create() method with no arguments.

But is there any other way ? Other than these two.
I am thinking it in C++ way. But Is there any way to do this in PHP (I expect negetive answer LOL)

Comment: _Why_ do you want to do this?

Comment: [`~Base()` should be either virtual or protected](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm) and as it is written now, it leaks a `Derived` object and you can't destroy that object because you would end up in an infinite loop creating and destroying objects in the destructor.

Comment: Cause these Derived Classes will be Instantiated Automatically by an UnPackerMachine <<standalone>>

Comment: @James McNellis: Ya right. I forgot. The Destructor Should be virtual But. That doesn't solves the Actual Problem mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's a way in PHP LOL:

```
abstract class Base {
    public final function __construct() {
        $this->constructImpl();
    }
    abstract protected function constructImpl();
}

class Derived extends Base {
    protected function constructImpl() {
        /* implementation here */
    }
}
```

Basically, you just have to mark the constructor final.

Comment: WoW Man. You made me Laugh Loud. nice trick.
better to say you are pulling PHP's leg.
never thought it will be that easy to do in PHP. I should keep some faith on it. LOL